# Should the [history] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Today [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293741/original-purpose-of-input-type-hidden) tagged [history](/questions/tagged/history). I was not sure if it is on topic, but the history tag says:

> Use this tag for questions about the history of a programming concept or feature.

I agree that my question is most likely not on topic for Stack Overflow, and it maybe would have been better to post this on Programmer SE. However, does the [history](/questions/tagged/history) tag make sense on Stack Overflow anyway? For me it seems that *"questions about the history of a programming concept or feature"* are off topic.

I know that there are a lot of good and on-topic questions tagged with [history](/questions/tagged/history), but they seem not to fall into this *"questions about history..."* category.

Comment: I agree. At worst, most of those questions are off-topic. At best, `history` is a meta tag and should be removed anyway.

Comment: Related/dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134391/how-should-the-history-tag-be-disambiguated

Comment: Looks like it's mostly being used for "browser history", "commit history" and similar uses.

Comment: Did you learn something new from that question?  Was finding out that hidden fields are useful to store state in a stateless protocol a new discovery to you that you may well use in the future?  Hopefully you did, the primary goal of SO is to *learn*.  That knowing the history of html evolution would have helped you know this is not untypical.

Comment: @UphillLuge yes of course I learned something, now I know what its original purpose was. What do you want to tell me with this comment?

Comment: @hammar: yes, but it's not *supposed* to be, by the tag's own description. I think that either the tag meaning needs to be revised or we need to untag those questions.

Comment: If we removed the [history] tag, where would a good place for history-of-computers-and-software type questions? [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Also, here's an example of a highly-voted but closed history question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515324/history-of-djangos-popularity

Comment: The history tag-wiki itself also mentions several tags that are more specific (and hence more appropriate) for the types of questions to which `history` is currently being applied: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info